# How can I get first 16 bit from byteArray in Android Java?

Tags: java, android

Can anyone give me a util method that will give me first 16bit from a bytearray in Android/Java?

Code:

```
 //Decode API response using Base64 decoder
            byte[] decodedResult = Base64.decode(apiResponse, Base64.DEFAULT);

            //get first 16 bit from decodedResult
            byte[] first16Bit =
```

DUMMY Example in Flex language:

```
//Storing First 16 bits of databytearray to ivByteArray
                var ivByteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                ivByteArray.writeBytes(dataByteArray,0,16);
//Storing from 16 bits to length of databytearray to encByteArray 
                var encByteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                encByteArray.writeBytes(dataByteArray,16);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-) from Java.

Ex.,

```
byte[] first16Bit = Arrays.copyOfRange(dataByteArray, 0, 16)
```

**Update**
I didn't noticed that in the question user has been asked about `bit` instead of `byte`, anyway, if you want first 16 bit you can use following.

```
byte[] first16Bit = Arrays.copyOfRange(dataByteArray, 0, 2)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the same thing which is done in flex which is written in my question?

Comment: but this is returning the first **128** bits (16 **bytes**)! wasn't question about **16 bits** ?!?!?

Comment: Yes the first two bytes would be `byte [] first2bytes = .....,0, 2);`. Again i'm amazed that an OP does not make excuses for causing confusion.

Comment: @PoojaSingh, I hope so, anyway you can try it and check whether this is same thing or not.

Comment: Can you please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370961/what-to-pass-in-cipher-dofinal-in-android-java

Comment: Hi, can you please solve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429082/how-can-i-observe-api-call-based-on-user-submit-button-and-at-same-time-getvalue